# How to perform Label click in C#?

Tags: c#, click, label

I have a label working as a button. I would like when I press a button the click event to this label to take action. for example

```
private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("I pressed this label and showed me this messagebox");
}
```

Now I want when I press this button, the label1 click event to be performed

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I want when I press this button something like this happens
    Label1.PerformClick();
}
```

Comment: You could just use a `Button`.

Comment: now here is the tricky question for you `Muhand Jumah` are you wanting show a message that says you clicked the button when it's a button or that you clicked the Label even though both invoke the same method..? if so that can be done as well by doing a `switch{} case{}` on the `sender`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label1_Click(sender, e);
}
```

now if you want to show a message of which control was clicked all in one method do the following

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control control = (Control)sender;
    var name = control.Name;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("I pressed this {0} and showed me this messagebox",name));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this.

**First:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label1_Click(sender, e); // Just call the Label's click handler
}
```

**Second:**

```
// Bind the Label1_Click handler to the button1 Click event, as they both use the same delegate
button1.Click += new EventHandler(Label1_Click);
```

With the second approach, note that in C# delegates are *multi-cast*, so both the `button1_Click` handler *and* the `Label1_Click` handler will be called when the button is clicked, in the order they were bound.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //What the label click do:
      MessageBox.Show("I pressed this label and showed me this messagebox");
}
```

Is that not easier?
Why do you want to do it ?

Comment: Well isn't really easier to do it this way, because what if I have so many codes? let say 100 line? if I just do what you said then I will have an extra 100 lines for no reason. So If I do that I will have only 1 extra line. You understand my point?

Comment: Create a function with all your `Label1_Click` code that will be called both from the label & button. I understand your point now.

Comment: That's a good way to do as well. but I would use this "label1_Click(sender, e);" as it's working perfectly! But Thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier for you to just include the lable click functionality with the button click. Maybe even separate each piece in their own method and call them from the button click. Here is how you'd call another click event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1_Click(sender, e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyLabel:Label
{
    public void PerformClick()
    {
        OnClick(new EventArgs());//InvokeOnClick(this,new EventArgs());
    }
}
```